# Can i develop iOS app that has ARkit for 6s and later, but the rest of the app to work on 5s

Tags: xcode, arkit

i am a high school student and i am deveoping my first app for competition (something like hackaton), and the rules say that the app must work on 5s and later, and iOS 8. I would like to implement ARKit into my app for availablr devices, but that is not the main point of app, so the app would be just fine without AR on 5s and 6. Is it possible to run the same app on those devices without AR or i need to make another app for them? Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the guidelines on how to ask a [good](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you would just need to check using [Declaration Attributes](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html).

For instance, when calling anything related to ARKit - meaning **iOS >= 11** -, you would check if the iOS version is available:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
  // Do anything related to ARKit
} else {
  // Fallback to manipulate a workaround to ARKit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check in the AppDelegate if the device supports ARKit, checking for iOS11 won't work as you could have an iPhone 6 on iOS11.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    guard ARObjectScanningConfiguration.isSupported, ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else {

        //ARKit not supported
    }

    return true
}
```